# Array out of bounds while index is correct

Tags: java

I'm doing this kata and the code should work, but What am I doing wrong? For an array like:
{1, 1, 2, 10, 3, 1, 12}

I get the below:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 7
at Main.SumMultiplier(Main.java:10)
at Main.main(Main.java:28)

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String SumMultiplier(int[] arr) {

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : arr){
      sum += arr[i];
    }
    int doubleSum = sum * 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++){
      for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (arr[i] * arr[j] > doubleSum){
          return "true";
        }
      }
    }
    return "false";
  }
```

Comment: `sum += i` - `i` is the value, not the index.

Comment: it should just be this       
 `for (int i : arr){ sum += i; }`

Comment: Replace with `int doubleSum = Arrays.stream( arr ).sum() * 2 ;`

Comment: Using semantic variables names rather than `i` and `j` might have helped your to avoid this flaw.

Comment: the array has 7 elements; when looping to the element `10`, that is, `i == 10`, `arr[i]` will fail since `10` is not a valid index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (int i : arr)`

This iterates over the values inside the array, NOT the indices of the array.
So inside the loop the integer i takes on the values `1, 1, 2, 10, 3, 1, 12`, NOT `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

This results in the IndexOutOfBoundsException with Index 10

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because you have used `arr[i]` in foreach loop. Here `i` represents integer value present in `arr` and not the index.
So when value of `i` is 10 you are trying to access `arr[10]` which is giving you index out of bound exception.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String SumMultiplier(int[] arr) {

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : arr){
      **sum += i;**
    }
    int doubleSum = sum * 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++){
      for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (arr[i] * arr[j] > doubleSum){
          return "true";
        }
      }
    }
    return "false";
  }
```